# Foundation drop-down not working in angular

Tags: jquery, angular, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

I am working with angular and foundation. When I place my toggle drop-down button in a table  it doesnt work. It gives this error shown below. But when I place it out the table it works.

```
 <table>
       <thead>
        .............
       </thead>
       <tr *ngFor="let purchaseOrder of purchaseOrders; let i=index;">
        <th>{{i+1}}</th>
        <td>{{purchaseOrder.createdAt}}</td>
        <td>{{purchaseOrder.lpoNumber}}</td>
        <td>{{purchaseOrder.supplier.supplierName}}</td>
        <td>n/a</td>
        <td>n/a</td>
        <td>n/a</td>
        <td>
        <div><button class="button" type="button" data-toggle="example-dropdown">Toggle Dropdown</button></div>
      </td>
      ........
    </table>
    <div class="dropdown-pane" id="example-dropdown" data-dropdown data-auto-focus="true">
        Example form in a dropdown.
     </div>
```

This is the error I get when I place it in the table in my console.

```
zone.js:192 Uncaught TypeError: elem.getBoundingClientRect is not a function
    at Object.GetDimensions (foundation.js:1117)
    at Dropdown._setPosition (foundation.js:3628)
    at Dropdown._setPosition (foundation.js:5807)
    at Dropdown.open (foundation.js:5940)
    at Dropdown.toggle (foundation.js:6004)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5183)
    at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4991)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.js:8249)
    at jQuery.fn.init.triggerHandler (jquery.js:8333)
    at foundation.js:670
```

NB":It works when placed outside the table.
Any help?

Comment: Can you provide a working codepen and some info about the used Foundation Sites version?

Comment: @DanielRuf I am using the foundation 6.4.3 in my angular project and when I run a foundation project in codepen, it does work when I place a modal or a toggle-dropdown in my table td. But I am thinking the problem here is foundation reloading. I have `$(document).foundation();` in my component also. So foundation should load after the DOM is finished. But in my table I am using an `*ngFor` so it must also be something with that as well